# Java File I/O -ftp busy error reading file error

Tags: java, file-io

Should i create multiple ftpproxyclient objects or the single one is enough?Since it is throwing ftp busy processing file error:

```
ftp = new FtpProxyClient(this.getFTPServername(hrGroupName), this.ftpPort,
                ftpUserName, getFTPPassword(hrGroupName));

ftp.setBinaryMode();

is = ftp.getFile(feedFileName);
```

//Do some processing and check for remaining files:

```
for (int i = personHeadDTO.getValueN().intValueExact() + 2; i < sequenceNo.intValueExact(); i++) {

                            fileName = feedFileName
                                    .replace(".", "_" + i + ".");
```

the below code is throwing ftp is busy error:

```
                            if(ftp.isFileExists(fileName)){
                                body1.append(fileName); 
                            }
                            else{
                                body1.append(fileName+" (Not Available in archive folder).");
                            }

                            body1.append(newline);
                        }
```

Comment: If the server is saying its busy, perhaps the server is busy.  You need to fix the source of the problem, or just keep trying until they fix it. ;)

Comment: can i use the same FtpProxyClient object for reading all the file names..

Comment: one ftp client is all you need. I suggest trying to test this with an FTP server which is not used much first.

Comment: Hi Peter ..Can you help me with the below info..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i remove the lines:

```
   ftp.changeDirectory("prxdpshr");
```

and

```
ftp.getFile(feedFileName);
```

I am getting no errors, there seems to be a problem when i get a file and then do some operations using the ftpclient object.

```
                      String feedFileName="intusa35a.csv";
        ftp = new FtpProxyClient("server", 21,
                "user", "pass");

        ftp.setBinaryMode();

        ftp.changeDirectory("prxdpshr");

         ftp.getFile(feedFileName);

        ftp.changeDirectory("prxdpshr/archive_bkp");


        is=ftp.isFileExists("intusa35a.csv");

        is1=ftp.isFileExists("HR_Dorf_FeedFile.csv");           


        //lin = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        //lin1 = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(is1));

        String fileName="";
        StringBuffer body1=new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 4  ; i < 10; i++) {                
            fileName = feedFileName
                    .replace(".", "_" + i + ".");
            if(ftp.isFileExists(fileName)){
                body1.append(fileName); 
            }
            else{
                body1.append(fileName+" (Not Available in archive folder).");
            }

            body1.append("\n");
        }

    }
```

I have used a seperate ftpclient for checking for emptiness.